# Как передать коллекцию Map из корутины?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Суть задачи в том что у меня есть класс (к которому обращаюсь из `MainActivity` раз в секунду, создавая много объектов), и там корутина которая создает и запускает движение `ImageView`, в корутине раз в 100 миллисекунд обновляются координаты этой передвигающейся `ImageView` (только по координате Y), до тех пор пока она не дойдет до края экрана, в формате `mutableMap<Int, MutableList<Int>> //(index to listOf(x, y)`.

```
//В отдельном классе

var mapWithCoordinates = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableList<Int>>() 

fun move(container: FrameLayout, index: Int) {
        val object = draw(container, index) //Создаем объект
        GlobalScope.async {
            while (...//условие) {
                mapWithCoordinates[index]?.removeLast() //Удаляем предыдущую координату Y
                ...//Перемещаем объект
                mapWithCoordinates[index]?.add(y) //Обновляем координату Y в коллекции
                delay(cellRate)
                (container.context as Activity).runOnUiThread {    
                    container.removeView(object)
                    container.addView(object)
                }
            }
            if (...//Условие касания границы) ...//Удаляем из коллекции
            (container.context as Activity).runOnUiThread {
                container.removeView(object)
            }
        }
    }
```

> В двух словах создаются 5-6 объектов с присваиванием индекса, нужно отслеживать и сохранять их координаты, которые обновляются в постоянном режиме.

Как при каждом обновлении координат можно передать этот `mutableMap` в переменную в условно `MainActivity` (или в любое другое), чтобы можно было к нему обратиться?
(Или другой способ решения поставленной задачи)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ответ на ваш вопрос кроется в `LiveData`. при работе корутина сетает данные в `LiveData`, а вы подписываетесь на ее обновления.
2. `GlobalScope` - плохой выбор. `async` - тоже плохо. лучше использовать скоупы, которые привязаны к ЖЦ чего-нибудь, а вместо `async` - `launch`.
3. лучше эту всю логику инкапсулировать во `ViewModel`. там будут и работать корутина на `viewModelScope`, и изменяться `LiveData`.

Comment: А не подскажите как можно инкапсулировать сюда ViewModel?
Сейчас добавил MutableLiveData, но после передачи Map превращается в null.

Comment: @Ivan ViewModel - это отдельная технология, тут быстро не расскажешь.